# Using MSBuild to buld a solution (.sln) with many projects in how can I make each project build into its own folder?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

I am trying to create a simple build process for a quite complex (many projects) vs2010 solution.

I wish for a folder structure such as this

```
-Build
   -Proj1
      -proj1.exe
      -proj1.dll
   -Proj2
      -proj2.exe
      -proj2.dll
......
   -Projn
      -projn.exe
      -projn.dll
```

What I am getting from my attempts below is

```
-Build
   -proj1.exe
   -proj1.dll
   -proj2.exe
   -proj2.dll
   -projn.exe
   -projn.dll
```

I currently have this as a .proj file.  (see below)

This builds things fine, however it puts everything in the "build" folder that I specify. I want each project to be in its own seperate folder within that 'build' folder. How can I achive this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildOutputDir>C:\Projects\BuildScripts\Build</BuildOutputDir>
  <SolutionToCompile>PathToSolution.sln</SolutionToCompile>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="Clean">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildOutputDir)" />
 </Target>

 <Target Name="Compile">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildOutputDir)" />
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionToCompile)" 
           properties = "OutputPath=$(BuildOutputDir)" Targets="Rebuild" />

 </Target>

 <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Compile">
  <Message Text="Clean, Compile"/>
 </Target>
</Project>
```

I call the .proj with a simple bat

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /nologo externalBuild.proj /m:2 %*
pause
```

I have also tried a more complex version ([copy and paste!](http://sedodream.com/default,month,2006-05.aspx)) that looks more like it should work, but still puts things in a single folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAll" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="path to solution folder\**\*proj" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>CI</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>



  <Target Name="CoreBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects ="@(ProjectsToBuild)"
             ContinueOnError ="false"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
      <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>    
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DestFolder>Build\</DestFolder>
  </PropertyGroup> 


  <Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(OutputFiles)"
          DestinationFiles="@(OutputFiles->'$(DestFolder)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanAll">
    <!-- Delete any files this process may have created from a previous execution -->
    <CreateItem Include="$(DestFolder)\**\*exe;$(DestFolder)\**\*dll">
      <Output ItemName="GeneratedFiles" TaskParameter="Include"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <Delete Files="@(GeneratedFiles)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Targets="Clean" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);"/>
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildAllDependsOn>CleanAll;CoreBuild;CopyFiles</BuildAllDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildAllDependsOn)"/>

</Project>
```

Comment: How did you resolved your problem? I have the same and the only solution - is to build projects, not solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Using devenv.com to build from the command line will do what you want. It will use the output directories specified in the project files. This is what we're using, because at the moment we don't need more control over the build mechanism.